# Remove all <tag></tag> with text between

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove all text tagged like this (including the tags)

```
<tag>TEXT</tag>
```

from a `String`.

I have tried

```
.replaceAll("<tag>.+/(tag)*>", "")
```

or

```
.replaceAll("<tag>.*(tag)*>", "")
```

but neither works correctly and I can't replace the tagged text with `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want, so here are a few options:

```
String text = "ab<tag>xyz</tag>cd";

// Between
text.replaceAll("<tag>.+?<\/tag>", "<tag></tag>"); // ab<tag></tag>cd

// Everything
text.replaceAll("<tag>.+?<\/tag>", ""); // abcd

// Only tags
text.replaceAll("<\/?tag>", ""); // abxyzcd
```

EDIT:

The problem was the missing `?` after the `.+`. The question mark only matches the first occurence, so it works when multiple tags are present which was the case.

Comment: my text is `<tag>localhost:8080//channels/2%f#aciZ7%Otz10iG)}Z!hjLk.jpeg</tag>okkk<tag>localhost:8080//channels/z#oSUHToVrC8H!{pdz1qhsnz6.jpeg</tag>ok<tag>localhost:8080//channels/lWy6DXPqG74hblc#VfYpDX51P.jpeg</tag>.` and after remove `<tag>.+<\/tag>` i must to have only `okkk.`, `<tag>.+<\/tag>` dont work for me, result is only one dot

Answer (score 0):

Change to this ,

```
 String nn1="<tag>TEXT</tag>";
 nn1=nn1.replace("<tag>","");
 nn1=nn1.replace("</tag>","");
```

OR

```
String nn1="<tag>TEXT</tag>";
nn1=nn1.replaceAll("<tag>","");
nn1=nn1.replaceAll("</tag>","");
```

Output : `TEXT`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i want to remove <tag></tag> with between text

Comment: so you want to remove '<tag>TEXT</tag>' all this? 

Then your code is working fine, but may be you are not saving it when doing replaceAll it.
I mean, nn1=nn1.replaceAll("<tag>.+/(tag)*>", "");

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regular expression.

```
.replaceAll("<tag>.+?<\/tag>", "<tag></tag>");
```

This removes all the tags whether it's an HTML or an XML tag.

Comment: this code remove all html tags, but i want to remove <tag></tag> with nested text between that

Comment: In that case you can user .replaceAll("<tag>", "").replaceAll("</tag>", "");

Comment: how about between <tag></tag> ?

Comment: what's the problem with .replaceAll("<tag>.+</tag>", "");

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void removeTAG()
{
    String str = "<tag>Your Long String</tag>";
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        str = str.replace("<tag>", "");
        str = str.replace("</tag>", "");
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Here what i did and output was as expected

**Output** Your Long String